# AutoIt to act as virtual server - is it possible?

Tags: virtual, autoit

First of all, hello :)

I seek an answer for question that bugs me for a while... i didn't actually start to write a code, just because i am uncertain if it's possible to make something like this with AutoIt.

My goal is to (i will be most specific here): when some app try to contact any IP out there, my script will act like that IP and return requested value. That's all :D Thanks in advance.

P.S. if it's possible, i will find a way to write it by my own, i will no bother you guys (maybe a little though :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible using AutoIt (assuming TCP or UDP protocol is used).